# How do I protect a contactor in arc weld circuit from wear?

Tags: safety, generator, voltage-measurement, high-current, contactor

I have a load banker (a toaster run by a 100 - 800 amp 10 - 40 V DC welder with non contact amp and volt sensors built in). I am trying to make an arc flash prevention unit for it.  Relay control with a switch can solve the arch flash. Protecting the relay is the problem. How do I keep the relay from closing when there is potential across the weld circuit?

The power involved has fried most of my attempts at voltage sensing, but I am probably doing it wrong as I don’t need a comparison, just whether it is present or not.

What kind of circuit am I looking for? What kind of parts will handle the power involved?

To further clarify:
[image: parts and diagram]

- A = the point of safety concerns. Manually placed cable twist lock cam connectors.
- B = Main voltage and amperage sensor board and display
- C = Hull sensors for the main board around the welding cable
- D = front panel on off switch for the load back display and fan
- E = some sensing apparatus for open circuit potential voltage to determine whether the welder is generating output before allowing actuation of the contactor. (Welder must be off for the contactor (NO) to engage. Once engaged the contactor stays engaged until the manual switches are thrown)
- F = load bank housing fan
- G = Contactor manual switch to be placed next to the main power with a linked safety quick off shroud
- CR = normally open 600 amp DC contactor with 12 VDC actuator circuit
- “?” = a circuit on PCB  most likely that will prevent the actuator for engaging while voltage is present across the open contactor. This prevents contactor wear from the high amperage and is an additional flash safeguard.
- G, CR, and “?” are not standard components on a load bank.

There is no way to send feedback to the attached welder, as the load bank is used in establishing correct functionality on a welder that is in for repair. An engine drive is obvious when making output, but a wall powered welder may generate output when in an “off” state and they have a capacitor bank charged to 900 V inside and a relay for power control that can fuse in the closed state. Injury has happened because the twist lock leads have been connected to a welder generating output when it shouldn’t. The flash from connecting leads with live current blinds easily. A contactor and switch pair solve the problem with arc flash but the contactor is a limited use wear item when used on an active output welder.

To reiterate the problem G and “?” are components I don’t know how to make it order to protect the relay from the amount of power involved. Electrometer is the only means I know of to detect potential in a circuit without completing the circuit, but so far it has proved too sensitive in the presence of industrial equipment.

Perhaps an alternative, not sure how to do it, would be to draw off power from the open circuit, 12v or so, and use it to power a normally closed low voltage relay to keep the operator from engaging the contactor. How would you draw off 12v from welder output power?

Comment: I cannot understand your question, and neither what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please use standard symbols in your drawing!

Comment: I guess the capacitor looking item a little to right from item CR is actually the switch of CR. And I guess you do not want anyone to turn that switch ON if there happens be the welding machine ON and connected to the rest of your system. I guess you want to prevent tearing and wearing the switch. The switch would obviously suffer as much if it's opened or closed when the welding machine is connected and ON, so you should prevent all state changes of that switch when the voltage from the the welding machine is present. Right?

Comment: Correct. Sorry, that contactor symbol is the standard on welder circuit diagrams. I didn’t think to comment on it.

Comment: (continued) Turning OFF should not be prevented for safety reasons - my opinion. Is there any possibility to affect the welding machine through wires if needed?

Comment: Welding machine does not respond via the welding cables (not true on all models). The load bank needs to remain agnostic to the model of the welder.

Comment: @user3011089  I do not want to get limited to the welding cable. I guess other wire is possible to be purchased and maybe connected to somewhere. But I have red that you inserted "There's no way to send feedback" so my question is obsolete.